# Getting a null value when submitting a form

Tags: node.js, forms, express, vue.js

I am a web developer and came across a small problem and would love to help.
I created a form page that contains input and I try to send data using a post method.

```html
<form action="http://localhost:3000/test" method="POST" class="card">
      <div><label for="nameinvstement">:שם השקעה</label></div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="nameInvstement" id="nameinvstement" required />
      </div>
      <form/>
```

On the server side I try to get the data I sent, using express.js, and mongodb, I grab the specific input by the name I set for it on the html page.
The problem is that it gives me a null value and I'd love to help.

```js
app.post("/test", async (req, res) => {
  const {
    nameInvstement
  } = req.body;
  try {
    await collection.insertOne({
      nameInvstement
     });
      res.status(200).json("OK");
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
});
```

I will also note that if I read through axios the reading works for me.
I think maybe the form was sent in a file which is not json I'd be very happy for help thanks in advance :)

```js
methods: {
    postNewUser() {
      this.$http
        .post(URL, {
          name: this.name
        })
        .then(function(res) {
          res.status(200).json("OK");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: maybe in your template not have v-model

Comment: Through axios it works for me with v-model. But form should be without it.
But thank you very much :)